# How to I get my local repo in sync wit ha file in master repo on github?

Tags: git, github

I am looking a file in master on git hub.

I am looking at the same file on my local repo but it is not reflect changes in the master file on the repo committed by someone else.

I tried git pull
git fetch and merge.

What else to I have to do?

Comment: Did you encounter any merge conflicts when you pulled?  Are you sure the change was committed in the same branch on the github repo that you're looking at locally?  You may want to try running a `git log -p filename` and see if that gives you any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no changes that you want to keep in your working folder, and assuming you did run fetch successfully, you can

```
git stash -u # safely clean up your working folder
```

Then point master to the remote's version (assuming your remote is called origin):

```
git merge --ff-only origin/master # if master is checked out
```

or

```
git push . origin/master:master # if master is not checked out
```

If you get an error with the last 2, you can add the `--force` option but remember to save the master to another branch or tag before doing so with

```
git branch temp master
git push origin yourname/temp
```

or

```
git tag -m "last master" temp
git push origin yourname/temp
```

the "yourname" part of the remote branch or tag is to let others know that it's your branch and you don't necessarily believe it to be valuable to others.